# Files on cygwin are created with wrong permissions

Tags: permissions, cygwin, file-permissions

I swiched to a new box at work and copied over my whole cygwin folder via `rsync` from the old box to the new one.
But now if I do `touch tmp`, the file gets `060` permissions and not `644` like before.
This is very disturbing, as not even `cat <<<foo` works but errors out with `bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: Permission denied`.

Comment: Which parameters did you use for `rsync` ? By default, file permissions are not preserved.

Comment: `rsync -avh --progress ...` so yes, permissions are preserved. Also I'm not complaining about the permissions of existing files, but newly created ones. Existing files are fine

Comment: To sanitize the ACLs, a `-b` switch was added to setfacl `setfacl -b foo` see http://superuser.com/a/1092296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this was an issue with the NTFS permissions. I also was not able to access the folders via Windows Explorer. After fixing the Windows permissions it works now as expected.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: As I said, I fixed the windows permissions. As far as I remember I opened the security properties in windows explorer, took ownership, removed all wonky permissions, added proper permissions, and force-inherited the permissions to children.

Answer (score 0):

New files get permissions according to set `umask`. Do `umask 022` for example and try again.

Comment: That **is** the umask in effect

Answer (score 0):

When using rsync a problem might be if the user on the old computer doesn't exist on the new one. In this case you might get the files saying that the user is the one on the old machine or the user is nobody. If this happens you might not have the permissions on your user to edit/modified (or even access) the synchronized data.

Comment: Nope, was a domain user that was identical and has the UID on the old and new system. Just the Windows permissions were somehow borked. After correcting those it worked as I wrote in my self-answer. :-)